# Saving a dataset with multiple tables

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

For a project I am working on, I am using a Access database which is downloaded of a server to store the data. Once the file is downloaded I open the database up and copy it into a dataset to make editing the data more easier.

The problem I have now is that I need to save the dataset back to an access database, but during the program execution I added new columns to the dataset aswell, So is there a way I can update the access database which is being stored on the E:\ drive after being downloaded with the new data and columns or would i have to create a new database from scratch.

Code I used to load and copy the dataset

```
private void accessConnect()
    {
        //Assign values to access database variables 
        Connection = new OleDbConnection();
        command = new OleDbCommand();
        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        databaseDataSet = new DataSet();

        //Assign location of database to connection variable 
        connection.ConnectionString =
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\EAttendance.accdb;" +
            "Persist Security Info=False";

        //Establish connection with database
        command.Connection = connection;

        //Copy all tables into a c# dataset 
        try
        {
            //Select the user table in the database
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users";
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            //Copy table into dataset 
            adapter.Fill(databaseDataSet,"users");

            //Select the students table in the database
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM students";
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            //copy the students database into the dataset 
            adapter.Fill(databaseDataSet, "students");

        }

        //catch exception and display error if application fails to read database 
        catch (OleDbException)
        {
            //Display error in form title bar
            this.Text = "Error #102 : Database Read Error";

            // Set connection value to false
            connectionBoolean = false; 

        }



    }
```

Comment: If you add new columns to the Dataset's table then you need to recreate those columns on the Access file. Saving a Dataset doesn't create the new columns on the Access file. There are commands that allows to alter an existing schema. You can find a [reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn123881.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you miss is the SQLDataReader

```
public SQLDataReader someReader
{
 get {return this.Reader("students");}
}
```